# Store Annotations in database

Tags: .net, wpf, annotations

Below is code to open annotations to / from file

How would I load and save the annotations to a database?

The database is MS SQL Server and I know how to read and write text, xml, and binary. Just need to know what kind of stream to use and how to use it.

I would rather not hold a connection to the database open. Something like read and then hold in memory and then write?

```
using System.Windows.Annotations;

private FileStream streamAnno;

private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{          
    /// Creates an annotation service based on
    /// a FlowDocumentReader control.
    AnnotationService service = AnnotationService.GetService(FlowDocumentPageViewer1);

    /// Checks if the service has not been instantiated.
    if (service == null)
    {
        /// Instantiates a FileStream object.
        streamAnno = new FileStream("tip100annotations.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate);

        /// Instantiates the annotation service.
        service = new AnnotationService(FlowDocumentPageViewer1);

        /// Creates an annotation store using the derived
        /// XmlStreamStore object and the FileStream object.
        System.Windows.Annotations.Storage.AnnotationStore store = new System.Windows.Annotations.Storage.XmlStreamStore(streamAnno);

        /// Sets the AutoFlush property to true to ensure
        /// that every annotation is flushed to the store automatically.
        store.AutoFlush = true;

        /// Enables the annotation service.
        service.Enable(store);
    }
}

private void Page_Unloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    /// Tries to get the annotation service.
    AnnotationService service = AnnotationService.GetService(FlowDocumentPageViewer1);

    /// If the annotation service is valid and is enabled
    if (service != null && service.IsEnabled)
    {
        /// Disables the service.
        service.Disable();

        /// Closes the stream
        /// 
        if (streamAnno != null)
        {
            streamAnno.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think I got is solved with a memory stream

The stream is stored in SQL as varbinary(max)

```
streamAnnoMem = new MemoryStream();
if (viewRawTextSdocsID != null)
{
    byte[] annotation = AnnotationGetUser((int)viewRawTextSdocsID);
    if (annotation.Length > 0)
    {                     
        streamAnnoMem.Write(annotation, 0, annotation.Length);
        streamAnnoMem.Position = 0;
    }
}

/// Instantiates the annotation service.
service = new AnnotationService(FlowDocumentPageViewer1);

/// Creates an annotation store using the derived
/// XmlStreamStore object and the FileStream object.
System.Windows.Annotations.Storage.AnnotationStore store = new System.Windows.Annotations.Storage.XmlStreamStore(streamAnnoMem);

/// Sets the AutoFlush property to true to ensure
/// that every annotation is flushed to the store automatically.
store.AutoFlush = true;

/// Enables the annotation service.
service.Enable(store);

AnnotationServiceActive = true;
```